# What's wrong with my code? I can run this fine on my vscode but it won't work on heroku, the prob comes from this code

Tags: python, heroku, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.py

What's wrong with my code? I can run this fine on my vscode but it won't work on heroku, the prob comes from this code

```
COGS = [path.split("\\")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./lib/cogs/*.py")]

class Bot(BotBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.PREFIX = PREFIX
        self.ready= False
        self.cogs_ready = Ready()

        self.guild = None
        self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

        db.autosave(self.scheduler)
        super().__init__(command_prefix=PREFIX, owner_ids=OWNER_IDS)

    def setup(self):
        for cog in COGS:
            self.load_extension(f"lib.cogs.{cog}")
            print(f"{cog} cog loaded")
        print("setup complete")
```

and the error I got is

```
2020-08-20T22:51:05.100470+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     self.setup()
2020-08-20T22:51:05.100473+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   File "/app/lib/bot/__init__.py", line 56, in setup
2020-08-20T22:51:05.100618+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     self.load_extension(f"lib.cogs.{cog}")
2020-08-20T22:51:05.100621+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 660, in load_extension
2020-08-20T22:51:05.100910+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
2020-08-20T22:51:05.100913+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 94, in find_spec
2020-08-20T22:51:05.101051+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
2020-08-20T22:51:05.101070+00:00 app[Worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.cogs.'
2020-08-20T22:51:05.196203+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-20T22:51:05.234805+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You split the path incorrectly. Right now your code works only on Windows.

You need to use `os.path.sep` instead of hardcoding `"\\"` because otherwise it fails on Linux where the directory separator is `"/"`.

But probably it'd be even better to use `os.path.split()` instead of manually messing around with the path. In general take a look at [the `os.path` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), you may have use for them!